# Executing two command lines at the same time

Tags: java

This is a piece of the code that I'm trying to do:

```
String intro = "Test String";
System.out.println("===============");  //Line 1
System.out.println(intro);              //Line 2
System.out.println("===============");  //Line 3
```

I was "animating" the intro, i.e. I use a loop to move the string one space to the right for each iteration. So for example, first time is "Test String", second time will be " Test String". I also use Thread.sleep() function to delay the animation. However, I couldn't print the Line 3 until the for loop finishes. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

EDIT:

This function is used to move the string:

```
public String moveChar(String a){
    char temp=' ';
    char[] charOfA = new char[50];
    charOfA = a.toCharArray();
    temp = a.charAt(a.length()-1);

    for (int i = a.length()-1; i > 0; i--) {

        charOfA[i] = charOfA[i-1];

    }
    charOfA[0] = temp;
    a = new String(charOfA);
    return a;
}
```

then the one on Main is:

```
System.out.println("==================================");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    intro = moveChar(intro);
    System.out.print(intro);
    System.out.print("\r");
    sleep(1000);
}
System.out.println("==================================");
```

Sleep function is just Thread.sleep(int milliseconds); with try-catch surrounding it.

Comment: can you paste the code that you have tried out ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add your loop and sleep() code as well please?

Comment: No, it is not possible with a simple `println`. You'd need special terminal control characters for that, which are specific to a terminal emulator this is run in.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* print backspace `\b` and erase whatever you printed to simulate an animation.

```
        String x = "Test String";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(x);
            int len = x.length();
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            {
                System.out.print('\b');
            }
            x = " " + x;
        }
```

I have no idea if this will work on all platforms. Seems to work on a Win7 command line.